# show/hide password bug - onmouseup not firing if the user presses down and drags away

Tags: javascript

I got this code below to show/hide password on a log in page. The code works but if the user presses the show/hide icon and drags away the mouseup event don't fire and the password stays visible.  How can I prevent this from happening?

```js
function showPassword() {
  document.getElementById('pwBox').type = "text";
}

function hidePassword() {
  document.getElementById('pwBox').type = "password";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> Password:
<input id="pwBox" type="password" value="" />
<i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true" onmousedown="showPassword()" onmouseup="hidePassword()" style="cursor:pointer;"></i>
```

Comment: Do you use the same functionality on other form elements on the page?

Comment: nope. ..........

Comment: A technique used since the last millennium is to add a mouseup event listener to the window-object. Then you will get the mouseup event even if it happens outside the browser window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using the **[`onmouseleave`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave)** event in addition to your [**`onmouseup`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseup):

```js
function showPassword() {
  document.getElementById('pwBox').type = "text";
}

function hidePassword() {
  document.getElementById('pwBox').type = "password";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> Password:
<input id="pwBox" type="password" value="" />
<i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true" onmousedown="showPassword()" onmouseleave="hidePassword()" onmouseup="hidePassword()" style="cursor:pointer;"></i>
```

This ensures that even a click-and-drag will trigger the function.

Hope this helps! :)